# Does 'invidious' imply hatred/malice for 'envy'?

Tags: meaning, etymology, confusables

> **[invidious](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/invidious) (adj)** =  (Of an action or situation) likely to arouse or incur resentment or anger in others
>
> [Etymology](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=invidious&searchmode=none): c.1600, from Latin invidiosus "full of envy, envious," from invidia "envy, grudge, jealousy, ill will" (see [envy](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=envy&allowed_in_frame=0))
>
> **[envy](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/envy) (noun)**= A feeling of discontented or resentful longing aroused by someone else’s possessions, qualities, or luck

The definition of **invidious** centres around hatred/malice, but because *invidious*'s etymology follows from **envy**, would someone please elucidate and explain if *envy* has ever meant hatred/malice? If not, then how did *invidious* connote hatred?

I am aware of the "Etymological Fallacy", but I'd like to know if the term **invidious** reveals another possible connotation of *envy* that I've overlooked until now.  Does the stated `discontented or resentful longing` for *envy* imply hatred/malice?

Comment: Sounds like more about sociopsychology and hardly about language. I do understand that usage dictates meaning, though.

Comment: Looks like you answered it yourself in your quoted text of the etymologies.

Comment: In U.S. usage _invidious_ commonly appears in the phrase "invidious discrimination"—a term given judicial prominence by Justice William O. Douglas in Skinner v. Oklahoma (1942). Although the notion of envy or resentment is perhaps implicit in the original usage, a more accurate synonym for _invidious_ in this legal context might be _stigmatizing_; and the sense of the term "invidious discrimination" might better be understood as "stigmatizing discrimination under color of law." The meaning "unjustly discriminatory" for _invidious_ emerges in the Webster's Collegiate Dictionary series ...

Comment: ...in the Third Edition (1916); the Second Edition (1910) had included only the meanings "envious" (labeled obsolete) and "likely to incur or produce ill will, or to provoke envy ; hateful." The evolution of _invidious_ in U.S. usage (as tracked by the changing definitions in MW's Collegiate Dictionaries over the years) is quite interesting. I regret that this question has been closed on the ground that it "can be answered using commonly-available references."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Invidious" or "envious" mean approximately the same thing, albeit the latter is far more common. They both can imply that feelings of hatred or resentment go along with them; however, before you can make that assertion, you'd need to read the sentence in context to see whether the person feeling invidious or envious of someone actually hates them.  I might feel envious/invidious of my best friend when he wins a hundred bucks in the lottery, but I certainly won't hate him.

Answer (score 0):

Neither word means, or has ever meant 'hatred' or 'malice'.

Comment: OK, then: neither word implies hatred or malice.

Comment: Please add some reasoning to your answer.

Comment: None of the dictionaries I have consulted mentions  'hatred' or 'malice' in the definitions of these two words. That's good enough for me.

Answer (score 0):

If I were forced to do something which had the potential to create problems, controversy, anger etc., I would regard it as an ***invidious responsibility***.

> Of an action, duty, topic, etc.: Entailing odium or ill will upon the
> person performing, discharging, discussing, etc.; giving offence to
> others.e.g. 1846   N. Hawthorne Mosses ii. viii. 148   (Earth's
> Holocaust) It would be invidious if not perilous to betray their awful
> secrets. (OED sense 2a.)